# Reconhecimento de voz no Android

Tags: android, reconhecimento-de-voz

Fiz algumas pesquisas e preciso de ajuda para implementação de reconhecimento de voz em uma aplicação com Android Studio, estou com algumas dificuldades em encontrar material de apoio.
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa criar uma intenção usando o [`RecognizerIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html). Veja a explicação no código:

```
// cria um intent usando para abrir a tela de captura de voz
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, 
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
// configuração para caputarar fala baseado no local padrão do dispositivo
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
// configuração definir titulo no alert 
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Fala alguma coisa agora");
try {
    // faz a chamadada do ActivityResult com o código de resgate
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    // mostra uma mensagem caso o dispositivo não possua suporte
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não há suporte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Você pode criar uma função e chamar executar o código por exemplo em um botão qualquer. Logo depois que o `intent` for finalizado após o termino da fala, será chamado o `onActivityResul`. Veja como ele deve ficar:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                // aqui recebe a fala do usuário depois intent desaparecer
                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                // esse txtSpeachInput é um TextView que você pode criar
                // para receber a voz do usuário usando result.get(0)
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

O `REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT` pode ser criado com qualquer valor. Ele apenas assegura que quando o `intent` for finalizado, o `onActivityResult` reconhecerá de acordo o valor atribuído a variável. Exemplo:

```
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 7;
```

Comment: White, obrigado pela ajuda, mas ao tentar seguir a sua orientação o seguinte erro acontece caindo na linha do catch do seu mesmo código:         "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }" eu fiz igual o seu código, apenas colocando o primiero bloco dentro do evento OnClick de um botão... Há algo a mais que eu precise fazer, alguma configuração a mais ?

Comment: @EduardoRafaelMoraes se está dando exception é porque o dispositivo que está testando não tem suporte a reconhecimento de voz. (Se foi isso q entendi). As configurações são exatamente essas para o básico. Criei um app só pra testar e funcionou perfeitamente. Qualquer coisa, detalhe mais seu problema aqui q tentamos resolver juntos.